# Allowing/Disallowing directory listings with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, directory

I have a wordpress site running, and currently anyone can view the uploads directory by visiting

```
http://site.com/wp-content/uploads
```

I want to stop this directory from being viewed in a browser but I want a subfolder to be viewable (eg. `http://site.com/wp-content/uploads/PublicUploads`). I have tried setting

```
IndexIgnore *
```

in the uploads folder, but I cannot work out how to set the sub folder back to visible.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most people use

```
Options -indexes
```

To make a subdirectory visible again, you'll need to put a .htaccess file inside that subdir, with `Options +indexes` inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Using mod_rewrite you can block direct access to `wp-content/uploads` directory like this:

```
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/?$ - [F,NC]
```

Keep in mind that this will only block browsing of `/wp-content/uploads` contents but will allow `/wp-content/uploads/PublicUploads` or any `/wp-content/uploads/foo`.